# How to get all children in kendo ui treelist?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

How can I get all the children for selected row in kendo ui treelist :

[image]

I want to get direct children for `Backframe` that would be level 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the datasource comparing the id of the row to the parentid of each row:

```
   change: function(e) {
      var selectedRows = this.select();
      if (selectedRows.length > 0){
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);
        var curID = dataItem.id;
        var ds = $(this)[0].dataSource.data();
        var children = [];
        for (var i=0; i<ds.length; i++){
          var pid =  ds[i].parentId;
          if (pid == curID){
            children.push(ds[i].Name)
          }
        }
        alert(children);
      }
     },
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/inoQo)**

Answer (score 0):

TreeList has [dataSource.childNodes](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/treelistdatasource#methods-childNodes) method for this purpose.

```
change: function(e) {
    var selectedRows = this.select();
    if (selectedRows.length > 0){
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);
        var children=this.dataSource.childNodes(dataItem);

        console.log(children);
    }
}
```